# How to find the elements of vector in matrix and arrange them?

Tags: matlab

There are two constructs namely a Matrix A(m x 8) and a vector B(n x 1), which is unique. All the elements of B are in A but each row in A has 4 elements from B arranged randomly. The question is: I want to find and locate that 4 element of B in each row of A, and to move those 4 elements to left most of matrix A or store in a new matrix C. How to do it fast.

To explain further,

```
          Matrix A =[1 3 10 5 2 20 30 35]
                    [2 4 25 35 1 5 12 13]
                    .
                    .
          Vector B = 1:9. Hence A has [1 3 5 2] and [2 4 1 5] of B in its first and second row. I want to locate those elements of B in
A and rearrange A or store anew like,
                     A=[1 3 5 2 10 20 30 35]
                       [2 4 1 5 25 35 12 13]
                          (or)
                       C=[1 3 5 2]
                         [2 4 1 5]
```

I tried to find and locate those elements using,

```
[I,J]=ismember(A,B)
```

and don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with a single reshape and ismember like this:

```
AT = A';
C = reshape(AT(ismember(AT,B)),4,[])
```

**Example:**

Suppose your `A` and `B` look like you described, then you can apply the solution:

```
A = [1 3 10 5 2 20 30 35
     2 4 25 35 1 5 12 13];
B = 1:9;

AT = A';
C = reshape(AT(ismember(AT,B)),4,[])'
```

Will give:

```
C =

     1     3     5     2
     2     4     1     5
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer my question. Luis Mendo solution suits me well. I also want to point out your solution fails with both data variables.

Comment: @Stoka What do you mean by 'my solution fails'? In both the example I give as well as the one Luis provides it does exactly what one would expect. If you mean I fixed the 4, that can easily be substituted by something like `sum(ismember(A(1,:),B))`

Comment: if I apply Luis Mendo to my data, I get C as [1 3 5 2; 2 4 1 5], but your suggestion gives [1 3 5 1;2 4 2 5]. Hence Luis Mendo solution is what I need. Thank you

Comment: Please execute your code with the given example. It is yet to be sorted.

Comment: @Stoka Seems like I didn't post the right version, it should work now and I have included a working example.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
At = A.'; 
[I,J]=ismember(At,B);
C = reshape(At(I(:)),[],size(At,2)).'
D = [C reshape(At(~I(:)),[],size(At,2)).'];
```

Your desired results are `C` and `D`.

Example:

```
>> A =
       1     3     4     5     7     6     8
       9     3     1     5     2     6     9

>> B =
       1     2     3     4     5

>> C =
       1     3     4     5
       3     1     5     2

>> D
       1     3     4     5     7     6     8
       3     1     5     2     9     6     9
```